# What is the correct behaviour of endIndex of array in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

The endIndex returns the same values as count.
Is it a correct behaviour or a bug?

```
var ar = [1, 2, 3, 4]
ar.count // 4
ar.endIndex // 4
```

Comment: I like this as a better alternative to what I thought endIndex was:  public extension Array {
    
    func lastIndex() -> Int? {
        guard !self.isEmpty else { return nil }
        return self.count - 1
    }
}

Answer (score 40):

`count` is the number of items in the collection, whereas `endIndex` is the [`Index` (from the `Collection` protocol)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/index) which is just past the end of the collection.

For `Array`, these are the same. For some other collections, such as `ArraySlice`, they are not:

```
let array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

array.startIndex  // 0
array.count       // 5
array.endIndex    // 5

let slice = array[1..<4]  // elements are "b", "c", "d"

slice.startIndex  // 1
slice.count       // 3
slice.endIndex    // 4
```

Comment: What is the purpose of having `endIndex` this way? What added functionality does it give because it seems a bit counter-intuitive.

Comment: For slices, the start/endIndex is kinda "label" of the elements, referencing the original position in the original array, which can be handy when you want to manipulate that.
For normal arrays, endIndex makes no special purpose other than count.

Comment: `.count` actually is a o(n) operation since it loops through the array to actually get the count, so `.endIndex` might be a better choice in some cases depending on what you want to do. For example, to access the last element in an array, you might want to do `array[array.endIndex - 1]` instead of `array[array.count - 1]`.

Comment: Where did you read that count is an O(n) operation? The Collection docs say that it is O(1) for a RandomAccessCollection, which Array is: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection

Comment: @CyberMew `count` is O(1) for Array (see the docs for [`RandomAccessCollection`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/randomaccesscollection) to which `Array` conforms.

Answer (score 17):

`Array.endIndex` is meant to be the 1 past the end of the array (or the same as count) for iteration purposes, not subscripting.

```
let x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for var i = x.startIndex; i < x.endIndex; i++ {
    println(x[i])
}
```

Comment: this seems to be very counter-intuitive

Answer (score 5):

There seem to be a lot of comments here that `endIndex` being `count` elements after `start` is counter-intuitive. I can't speak to what's intuitive to one person or another, but it's not random. It's a very sensible way for it to work.

I believe some folks are thinking of indexes like this, with the index pointing directly at the "box" containing the value:

```
|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|  0  |  1  |  2  |  3  |
|-----|-----|-----|-----|
   ↑                 ↑
 start              end
```

But this is not the right way to think about them. The correct way is this, with the index pointing to the border that you would begin reading the value from:

```
|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|  0  |  1  |  2  |  3  |
|-----|-----|-----|-----|
↑                       ↑
start                 end
```

If one begins at the start and advances `count` times, one should expect to be at the end, and that's what this achieves.

Consider now the case of the empty list:

```
|
|
↑
start
↑
end
```

Everything works exactly as expected. If you begin at `start` and advance 0 elements, you arrive at `end`. I say "advance" here on purpose. Indexes don't have to be integers. They just have to be something that has an "advance" operation and an end.

If `endIndex` were instead the "index of the last element," what would it be for an empty list? There is no last element. Making it -1 would be a possible dodge when indexes are signed integers, but Swift doesn't require Collection indexes to be integers at all (in fact, they usually aren't; Array is very unusual). Swift could make `endIndex` Optional, but that makes the math even uglier.

As HangarRash notes in the comments, for Collections with Int indexes that don't start at zero (ArraySlice and sliced Data in particular), `endIndex` wouldn't be `count - 1` in any case. For an empty slice, even offsetting with `startIndex + count - 1` wouldn't be -1 any more (so you can't just check for -1 to mean "empty"), and could point into the containing Array, which would clearly be wrong. On the other hand, the rules `endIndex = startIndex + count` and "empty collections have startIndex == endIndex" still work identically for slices. This approach is consistent over a wide variety of cases without requiring work-arounds.

This insight that the distance from the start to the end should be the count (rather than one less than the count), long predates Swift and is closely related to why many languages number arrays from zero rather than one. [Dijkstra was discussing this in 1982](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html). ("the difference between the bounds as mentioned equals the length of the subsequence") Counter-intuitive as it seems (and I certainly find it surprising at times!), this approach has been very powerful. It's not about performance or "C uses pointers" or anything like that. It's because it makes algorithms more beautiful.

Comment: And let's not forget the the situation with Array slices. There, the slice's count and endIndex have nothing to do with each other.